# Vue select tag on change not firing when selecting the same option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select tag that should trigger function when an option is selected.

```
<select id="selector" class="form-control" @change="executeAction" v-model="selectedAction">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select action</option>
  <option value="view">View Details</option>
  <option value="edit">Edit</option>
  <option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>

methods: {
    executeAction() {
        console.log('action is se', this.selectedAction);
    },
}
```

Now, what I expected was:

- When selecting the same option for the second time (For example: `View Details`), it should log the selected option.

What I got:

- It's not firing at all, I need to select other option so that I can reselect the `View Details` again.

What I tried:

- Using `watch`, and the result was the same.
- Using `@input` instead of `@change`, still result was same.
- Usin `v-on:` instead of `@`, still no luck.

Is this a bug? or wrong implementation?

Anyways, would be great to have an answer to this.

Comment: You are not changing nor inputing anything. Use @click (on options maybe) if you want this functionality.

Comment: @digitalniweb I'm afraid you cannot attach events on options

Comment: @devmedeveper were you able to get this to work? I have similar use case and was looking at options on how we can achieve it.